# Internal widows don't show up in desktop pane

Tags: java, model-view-controller, factory-pattern, jinternalframe

After little research on the Internet, I created a desktop pane and I want to put internal frames. I use the factory pattern to create multiple internal frames (windows)

I have the abstract class

```
import javax.swing.*;
public abstract class InternalWindowTemplate extends JInternalFrame{
JInternalFrame internalWindow;

public final void createInternalWindow(String title, int width, int height, int xOffset, int yOffset, boolean isResizable, boolean isClosable, boolean isMaximizable, boolean isIconifiable){
    internalWindow = new JInternalFrame(title, isResizable, isClosable, isMaximizable, isIconifiable);

    setInternalWindowSize(width, height);
    setInternalWindowLocation(xOffset, yOffset);
    internalWindow.setVisible(true);
    internalWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JInternalFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     try {
        internalWindow.setSelected(true);
     } 
     catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException exception) {
         exception.getMessage();
     }
     catch(Exception exception){
         exception.getMessage();
     }
}
 public void setInternalWindowLocation(int xOffset, int yOffset){
    setLocation(xOffset*getInternalWindowCounter(), yOffset*getInternalWindowCounter());
}

public void setInternalWindowSize(int width, int height){
    setSize(width,height);
}
}
```

and then I create a commandWindow:

```
import internalFrame.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CommandWindow extends InternalWindowTemplate {
   public CommandWindow(){
    createInternalWindow("Command window", 60, 40, 30, 30, false, true, false, false);
   }
}
```

Finally, I create the view for my GUI

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DesktopView extends JFrame{
private JDesktopPane desktop;
InternalWindowTemplate commandWindow;

public DesktopView(){
    //Make the big window be indented 50 pixels from each edge of the screen.
    int inset = 50;
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setBounds(inset, inset, screenSize.width  - inset*2, screenSize.height - inset*2);

    //Set up the GUI.
    desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    commandWindow = new CommandWindow();
    desktop.add(commandWindow);
    setContentPane(desktop);
}
}
```

When I try to run it in main

```
public class DesktopApp {
public static void main(String[] agrs){
    DesktopView desktopView = new DesktopView();
    desktopView.setVisible(true);
    desktopView.setDefaultCloseOperation(DesktopView.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

I only get the "big" window, but not the internals. What am I doing wrong? Is there something that I don't see? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your InternalWindowTemplate extends JInternalFrame AND has an instance of JInternalFrame. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: If I could have a constructor inside the abstract class, I would use `super()` in order to define the internal window. How am I supposed to do this, if not using a `JInternalFrame` object?

Comment: ok, got it, just removed the `extends` statement. Thank you